# SQL to get DISTINCT date values from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a field in a table named startdate and what I would like to do is run as little queries as possible to obtain a list that would display as the following:

```
2012

January
March
October

2011

September
November
```

The only dates that I want to show per year are the dates where there is a record for.

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you only want to show distinct "Months" found in a table or are you in fact looking for distinct "Date" values?

Comment: Distint months, I can get Distint months and years, however these are in 2 queries, I would like to almost combine them so that for each distinct year it selects all the distinct months within that year.

Answer (score 2):

This query can be used to find all distinct Year/Month combinations in a table for a given date (here start date).

```
SELECT     YEAR(startdate) AS DYear, MONTH(startdate) AS DMonth 
FROM         tablename
GROUP BY YEAR(startdate), MONTH(startdate)
```

After you have your results back in whatever way you choose to get them you can do something like this:

```
$year = 0;
  while ($row) { //loop through your rows here using while or foreach
    if($year != $row['DYear']){
      echo '<h1>'.$row['DYear'].'</h1>';
      $year = $row['DYear'];
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$row['DMonth'].'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
  }
```

Comment: Great :) This does give me the results that I need however, I would like a little help in arranging these into a format that I would like. Currently it returns an array that looks like the following:

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [DMonth] => 6
            [DYear] => 2010
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [DMonth] => 10
            [DYear] => 2012
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [DMonth] => 12
            [DYear] => 2010
        )
)

I would prefer it to be like:
Array([2010] => Array([Month] => 6 [Month] => 12)[2012] => Array([Month] => 2010))

Answer (score 0):

Using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), you could do something like:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$qry = $dbh->query('
  SELECT DISTINCT
    YEAR(startdate)      AS year,
    MONTHNAME(startdate) AS month
  FROM
    my_table
  ORDER BY
    startdate
');

if ($qry) {    
  $row = $qry->fetch();
  while ($row) {
    $current_year = $row['year'];
    echo '<h1>',htmlentities($current_year),'</h1><ul>';
    do {
      echo '<li>',htmlentities($row['month']),'</li>';
    } while ($row = $qry->fetch() and $row['year'] == $current_year);
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct column1, column2, column3... from table where columnx <> "" order by year, month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(startdate), MONTHNAME(startdate)
FROM   mytable
ORDER BY YEAR(startdate) desc,  MONTH(startdate) asc;
```

should do the trick, however the output will be:

```
2012 January
2012 March
2012 October
2011 September
2011 November
```

you can use the code given by eggyal to convert this into a format that you are looking for. Note that you will need to order on MONTH and not MONTHNAME (unless you want alphabetical order)

Answer (score 0):

As other posts have given your answer, I am going to provide information on *why* these answers work.

In an SQL select statement you can provide keywords. Specifically for MySQL you can provide `ALL, DISTINCT, DISTINCTROW`(and others unrelated to distinct rows).

The latter two options are actually the same option and yield the same results. The default select statement with no keyword uses `ALL` which returns all results. By passing in `DISTINCT` you eliminate any duplicate entries.

A duplicate entry is an entry where all the fields are the same, However, it should be noted that if you have an auto-incrementing primary key each row is distinct from the last as the pk is different. In order to select a distinct value with this kind of setup, you would need to specify a separate column name that is truly distinct.

For more reading on MySQL SELECT statements refer to the [users guide's select section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Hopefully I didn't provide information you have already gathered from the provided answers, but I have always found understanding "why" and "how" often allow me to understand when a particular solution will work, as well as when it won't work.